# How exactly do triple photon entanglements behave?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons, quantum-entanglement

I recently learnt that more than two photons can be entangled.

1. Are all the three photons are expected to have the same polarized angle due to entanglement?
2. Does measuring one of the three photons collapse the entire entanglement or the other two photons continue to be entangled?

Comment: 1.  It depends on how they're entangled.  2.  It depends on how they're entangled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, 3 photons can be entangled.  There are 2 common N=3 states for this:

GHZ=|000> + |111>

W=|100> + |010> + |001>

These states are somewhat complicated to understand, and it gets progressively more complicated as N increases.  The answers to your questions:

1. Yes for GHZ, measuring one tells you the polarization of the other two.  The answer is No for W states, measuring one does not allow you to predict the polarization of either of the other two.
2. Yes for GHZ, measuring one causes collapse of entanglement.  No for W, the other two remain entangled after measuring one.  (Here I am using the word "collapse" in its usual sense in quantum descriptions.)

Comment: In what sense are these two states more "common" than any other?